# WCF HTTP Proxy returning JsonObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf

I am creating WCF Http proxy. To pass on the calls to the backend APIs directed from Azure using WCF relay binding.

Problem is return type in WCF cannot be JsonObjects and the client don't want to parse the incoming string to Json.

As my WCF proxy service(light weight) don't want to know the data structure of the objects. So no data contract in my service.

How to pass the Json payload from downstream APIs to upstream Mobile App.
Any help thanks

Comment: Am I a god if I return json via wcf?

Comment: You deserve it.. hands down @MarcoSalerno